# Access Static Resources through Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jax-rs

I have web.xml configuration in which i map the url to the html page. The problem is that this html page has links to js, css, font files that are in the same or in the sub directories and server returns 404 by default because no explicit mapping exists.

How can I get all this static file (but only on specific prefix)?

I have tried do the following.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>myPage</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.test.MyPageServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myPage</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/myPage/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

MyPageServlet.java

```
@Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(... omitted));
        OutputStream outputStream = resp.getOutputStream();
        int BUFF_SIZE = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
        try {
            int byteRead = 0;
            while ((byteRead = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        } finally {
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

Firstly I implemented it by myself and then came across on this [article](https://blog.e-zest.com/access-static-resources-through-servlet/) (solution #2) where it is stated the same i have done earlier.

The problem is that received output is not readable so browser cannot interpret it. I`ve also tried do this reading file as a string but it fails in case of binary (icons, fonts, etc)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Let the default servlet handle static files.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha But will this work only with my prefix `myPage/*` ?. I mean if i want get `myPage/js.js` I will get it, but if i want get `myPage2/js.js` then I want return 404. Will it work this way?